# Why does my footer have a huge gap?

Tags: html, css

Example1:
http://codejanitor.us/nightclub2/work.html
The footer is the correct width, but there a huge gap. Examine: http://codejanitor.us/nightclub2/images/footerwide.gif

Example2:
http://codejanitor.us/nightclub2/work2.html
The footer is too thin, but there a NO gap. Examine: http://codejanitor.us/nightclub2/images/footer.gif

The two footer images are the same size....why is there a gap with one???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `p` element has a margin set, if you remove that the gap will disappear. Also I recommend you use firebug extension to easily discover these small bugs.

Comment: Equally, Internet Explorer 8 has a debugger which is pretty easy to use too :o)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the  inside  has margin set to 20px 0 which is creating the gap.

In the other example, the structure is different.

Comment: which element exactly has this margin? The css and code are exactly the same for both pages. So be more explicit please

Comment: #footerwide p is the element.  the style creating the problem is p on line 18 of your style.css.  it is called #footer p on your other page and you have specifically set that style on line 125 of style.css, that is why the effect is different.

Comment: hunterp, if you took my advice on the margin it would be nice to "accept" the answer...

Comment: Apparently he was changing the code as we were answering. Comment deleted.